# Pre-80s book about a man and a woman forced to fight golden "superior" aliens

Tags: books, story-identification

I'm looking for a book about a human man who, along with a human woman, is forced to fight against aliens who are described as being a golden man and woman, very strong, beautiful and "superior".

I read it in 1979-1981, I would like to read it again but I cannot remember the title.  I believe both the human couple and the alien couple were abducted by another group of aliens.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 6):

What you are describing appears to be [Transit](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2324182.Transit) by Edmund Cooper (1964).

[image]

A synopsis from goodreads.com:

> Plot: Richard Avery is on auto-pilot after his one true love dies
>   young of cancer. He gets whisked off by a mysterious someone, and
>   plopped on a planet with three other people. We get, that start a
>   'Robinson Crusoe in space', but it turns out that there are 'golden
>   ones' who have a similar colony of four on the same island, and
>   they're not friendly.

Comment: Hi Paul,

Thanks for your answer to my question!  I looked at the book ... and that isn't the one I was looking for (I guess they made a lot of stories about human vs alien conflict back then).  :-)

Thanks again, and Happy New Year!